# How to inject Google Maps API key into an Android application?

Tags: android, google-maps

I work in a team of several developers. We are developing an Android application that uses Google Maps. Since every one of us has different debug keystore, each of us has different API key. What is the best way to allow every developer (and build server) to automatically substitute his own key into the application when it is built?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We used a properties file where we stored our key inside (saved that in assets/config.properties). The only issue with that is that you have to create the MapView programmatically and not in your xml because the api key can only be added dynamically in the constructor.

Comment: This solution is not compartible with using Subversion.

Comment: It is. We have a sample properties file where all basics are set up. You just create your own file and ignore it for subversion. In this case you have to setup the properties file once when you checkout the source. We have this in our development setup and the build server has his own properties file. If the properties sample is newer than the own copy, the build brakes. So managing one file every few weeks is the only possible solution I know so far. If you have a better idea, please share it...

Comment: Thank you, now this makes sense. In the end, we ended up using similar solution, but with a resources file. An ant script took value from `local.properties`, injected it into a template and created file `resources/values/api_keys.xml`. Unfortunately, we couldn't integrate this approach with Eclipse in a bug-free way, but at least the missing resource is easily seen.

Answer (score 4):

You can follow the below process

in `strings.xml` file add the following line

```
<string name="mapkey">your api key</string>
```

Use the following in your map xml

```
android:apiKey="@string/mapkey"
```

So the developer have to make change in `strings.xml` file only.

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: This solution is not compartible with using Subversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can share your `debug.keystore` file between your team. You can find it in root folder of your project. Eclipse doesn't override it if it already exists so you can use the same debug keystore as your mates. So you all will have the same Map API key.

Comment: There is no `debug.keystore` in the root of the project. There is one in my home folder, though, but I don't like the idea of sharing that, because sometimes I work on several projects with different teams. Also, on the build server we have several builds (QA build, release build, etc) with different keys.